# Cassandra read overload on a single node

Tags: cassandra

Since few weeks we have an un-understandable overloaded node on a cassandra 2.1.8 cluster. ReadStage thread pool is often full and there are many dropped tasks on this node and only this one.
The node receives globally arround twice the load of other nodes.
It is a 9 nodes cluster and the RF is 3.

The Snitch is a network topology but the topology file is the default one. So the nodes are all considered to be in the same rack and the same datacenter.

When we choose a single data hosted on this node and we try to select it many times from cqlsh (with `consistency one`), the data is required at 90% from the overloaded node (seen with `tracing on`). This happens even if the data is also hosted on the node i am connected to with cqlsh.
We tried to isolate the node in a specific rack in the topology, but it didn't changed anything.

The node has been removed (decommission) and added again.
And another node has been added this week-end (there were previously only 8 nodes in the cluster).
But nothing changes about the overloaded node.
The coordinator of new node also prefer the overloaded one.

The problem is only on read requests.
There isn't any problem with mutations.

What might explain this ?
Is there anything other than the snitch for a coordinator to choose which node it will request ?
What could we do to fix this ?

Thank you for any suggestion.

EDIT :

The problem is raised on several tables. However, for information, this the description of the table on the which we did the tests :

```
CREATE TABLE main.app (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  acc uuid,
  apdex_f int,
  apdex_t int,
  cnx uuid,
  iid bigint,
  name text,
  prod boolean,
  sla_active boolean,
  st ascii,
  techno text,
  tz ascii
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
  AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
  AND comment = ''
  AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
  AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
  AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
  AND default_time_to_live = 0
  AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
  AND max_index_interval = 2048
  AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
  AND min_index_interval = 128
  AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
  AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

This is the query tested :

```
SELECT name from app where id = 630bbc5e-387a-424a-a8a3-e4948ec7470a;
```

This is the trace (I have just been executing it 10 times and had nearly the same result than this one)

```
 activity                                                                                            | timestamp                  | source     | source_elapsed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------+----------------
                                                                                  Execute CQL3 query | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.866000 | 172.16.0.1 |              0
 Parsing SELECT name from app where id = 630bbc5e-387a-424a-a8a3-e4948ec7470a; [SharedPool-Worker-7] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.867000 | 172.16.0.1 |             36
                                                           Preparing statement [SharedPool-Worker-7] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.867000 | 172.16.0.1 |            135
                                                 reading data from /172.16.0.8 [SharedPool-Worker-7] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.868000 | 172.16.0.1 |            354
                         Sending READ message to /172.16.0.8 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/172.16.0.8] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.868000 | 172.16.0.1 |            394
                      READ message received from /172.16.0.1 [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.16.0.1] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.935000 | 172.16.0.8 |             43
                                      Executing single-partition query on app [SharedPool-Worker-18] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.935000 | 172.16.0.8 |            479
                                                 Acquiring sstable references [SharedPool-Worker-18] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.935000 | 172.16.0.8 |            500
                                                  Merging memtable tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-18] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.935000 | 172.16.0.8 |            518
                                                  Key cache hit for sstable 5 [SharedPool-Worker-18] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.935000 | 172.16.0.8 |            544
                                  Seeking to partition beginning in data file [SharedPool-Worker-18] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.935000 | 172.16.0.8 |            560
    Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [SharedPool-Worker-18] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.936000 | 172.16.0.8 |            747
                                   Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables [SharedPool-Worker-18] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.936000 | 172.16.0.8 |            772
                                            Read 1 live and 0 tombstone cells [SharedPool-Worker-18] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.936000 | 172.16.0.8 |            808
                                            Enqueuing response to /172.16.0.1 [SharedPool-Worker-18] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.936000 | 172.16.0.8 |            873
             Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /172.16.0.1 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/172.16.0.1] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.936000 | 172.16.0.8 |           1119
          REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /172.16.0.8 [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.16.0.8] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.937000 | 172.16.0.1 |          70396
                                         Processing response from /172.16.0.8 [SharedPool-Worker-11] | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.937000 | 172.16.0.1 |          70431
                                                                                    Request complete | 2015-11-02 19:03:19.936484 | 172.16.0.1 |          70484
```

This data is present on the node I was connected to (172.16.0.1).

Another strange thing I just noticed: the new node (added last week-end) already holds more data (3.5 times more) than the overloaded one even if it has been added to the cluster nearly 10 days after.

Comment: What's the query and/or schema you're using? My initial thought is you have either a lot of tombstones, or a very large partition on that node. If you look at the tracing, it'll tell you that there are a lot of tombstones. If not, check the system log on that node and search for 'large partition' - if there is one, it'll show up there and should also give you the partition ID for it as well.

Comment: No tombstone appear in the trace.
The test request is on a quite small CF, I edit the message with the complete table description.

Comment: In fact i was wrong. There are tombstone. I added the trace to the question.
Anyway, I don't understand why coordinator behaviour would be depending on tombstone.

Comment: Thanks for adding more info - definitely not a large partition issue since you're not even using clustering columns. There's 70ms between sending the request from .8 to .1 which could be a number of things - GC pauses, simply a big data payload, network/hardware issues...if you're running other processes/applications on those servers, it could interfere as well. Anything stand out in the system.log? warnings, errors, GC messages?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The .8 node is on a dedicated server and it is a physical machine. The cassandra process is alone using the 8 CPU cores. The gc log is active and there are very few gc pauses. The latency is the consequence of the overload : the ReadStage thread pool is often full (32) and there are some times up to thousands of pending tasks. What i don't understand is why do coordinators requests this node 90% of the times whereas this data is on two other nodes.

Comment: Hi Thomas, sorry for the late reply - What's the token distribution like? The only reason why I'd think that node would get hit more often is if it owns more token ranges than the rest of the nodes. I can't really think of any reason why else - the DataStax drivers (even CQLSH which uses the Python driver I believe) can be latency and token aware (which should be default) so if data was distributed evenly around the DC, it should hit the different replicas if the primary is overloaded.